# Javascript - get value from textbox at every keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, alert, onchange

I have a textbox and I want to use the data in it every time something is entered; letter by letter.

What is happening is that when a value is entered, the Javascript is being executed *before* the value is actually put into the textbox, meaning that it always lags one character behind.

```
$(document).ready(
      function() {
          $('#test').keypress(

          function() {
            var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
            alert(value);
          });
      })

<input id="test" type="text"  />
```

Here's whats happening:

```
input alert
  w    ""
  e    "w"
  a    "we"
  l    "wea"
  t    "weal"
  h    "wealt"
```

Whereas I want it to happen dynamically; i.e. when I enter "w" I want the alert to contain "w" immediately after.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`keypress` happens before the change, yes. `keyup` happens after. Listen to that instead.

Answer (score 4):

You should try `keyup` event, because `keypress` happens before symbol is being input in a textbox

Answer (score 4):

use keyup

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#test').keyup(
            function() {
                var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
                alert(value);
            });
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyup` to read the valid after something has been entered. Here's how to do it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').keyup(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gEBc4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead -:

```
         $('#test').keyup(    
           function() {
             var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
             alert(value);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` instead, take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gEBc4/1/

Answer (score 0):

use keyup instead
that will work

```
$(document).ready(
      function() {
          $('#test').keyup(

          function() {
            var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
            alert(value);
          });
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'keyup' event instead of 'keypress'.

Change to:

```
$(document).ready(
      function() {
          $('#test').keyup(
          function() {
            var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
            alert(value);
          });
      });
```

Working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHko3xc6AdE57VvVxzGD?p=preview).